# What is the right way to talk about user events in an AB experiment as random variables drawn from distinct distributions in a test?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, random-variable, terminology, ab-test

Say we have a well setup A\B test that puts half of users in one arm, half in another. We are testing clicks on a website.

I'm trying to understand how to speak about the impressions as draws from a hypothesis test that assumes the impressions are from a single Binomial random variable, while we measure parameters for the hypothesis that the groups are drawn from different distributions.

Is this specification of the test correct?

- We assume the impressions from each arm are realizations of IID random variables drawn from a Binomial distribution with unknown parameter, $p$. This is the null hypothesis for a statistical test in which the alternative hypothesis is the realizations in group1 are drawn from a Binomial distribution parameterized by $p_1$, distinct from the Binomial distribution that group2 are drawn from, which parameterize by $p_2$, where $p_1 \neq p_2$.

I feel like conceptually I sort of know what I'm talking about here. But I cannot quite put it into crisp verbiage.